# How To Make Effective Use Of GPU For A Heavy JavaScript Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, gpu

Because of the complicated application that I'm building, the `JavaScript` is pretty huge. Some of the widgets are also quite heavy when it comes to mobile website terms.

Can we transfer the load of some selected widgets, which we feel is heavy, to the GPU to decrease the execution time of the widget?

Comment: Your question contains zero specifics.  Conceptually, some types of CSS that might use the GPU could be used in place of some javascript, but it's entirely dependendent upon exactly what you're doing in your javascript and what the target device's browser/GPU capabilities are.  General javascript cannot be offloaded to the GPU.

Comment: You could look at replacing some of the extremely heavy jQuery bits by vanilla javascript. The performance differences can be [quite substantial](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-vanilla-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

A very short answer: No.

A longer answer: a) Javascript is a single-threaded system, and b) you don't have access to the hardware at that level.

If you have something that's time consuming that can be offloaded to a background thread you could use a WebWorker to handle that portion of the processing. Note that Webworkers don't have access to the `window` object, so you can't update the screen with them.

There's an introduction to WebWorkers [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) and a more complete reference at MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers)

Comment: Also something to keep in mind with WebWorkers is that, the information passing between main thread and webworker is currently very limited. Only primitives and select objects (like array buffers) can be passed between the two.